# Confusing behavior when checking for values in a pandas series which contains both strings and integers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series of `dtype: object` that contains both numbers and characters. When I wanted to check if a certain value exists in that series I got confused by the way how the existence of a certain value is checked.

For the example below, I would intuitively expect, that `'a'` is in the series and also `'1'`. Furthermore, I wouldn't expect that the (integer) value `1` exists in the series, because AFAIK the `dtype: object` in pandas  can be (roughly?) compared with python's string type.

Does anyone has an an explanation for this behavior?

```
s = pd.Series(['a',1,2])

if 'a' in  s: 
    print('a is in s')
else:
    print('a is not in s')
if '1' in s:
    print('string 1 is in s')
else: 
    print('string 1 is not in s')
if 1 in s:
    print('integer 1 is in s')
else:
    print('integer 1 is not in s')
```

Output:

```
a is not in s
string 1 is not in s
integer 1 is in s
```

Comment: Interesting, if you do `a in s.values` , it gives `True`

Comment: But it gives `False` for `'1' in s.values`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are querying `1 in s` you are actually asking if it is in `s.index`. Note that `0 in s` will also be True.

If you define s in the following way - `s = pd.Series(['a',1,2], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])`

Then -

`1 in s #False`

`'a' in s #True`

And it has nothing to do with the values themselves.

Comment: Aha, that solved it. I find that behavior very counterintuitive, but of course that's subjective and up for discussion. It would make more sense for me if it was the other way around, so if I type `x in s` it should check for `x in s.values` by default and not for `x in s.index`